# get JSON field in python

Tags: python, json

I am new to python.

I have a  array of JSON responds like this (from the API of theMovieDB), this is the first member of the array responds[0]:

```
{
page: 1,
results: [
{
poster_path: "/yVHNGrsIj3FNDg9lgseiZMlHbjJ.jpg",
adult: false,
overview: "The film centers on three brothers who, upon learning they only  have a few days left to live, set off to reverse a lifetime of mistakes. Hopper and Simmons are playing the brothers' father and uncle, respectively, while Caan is one of the brothers. Helfer is Caan's girlfriend, a woman with a dangerous past.",
release_date: "2010-09-17",
genre_ids: [
   35,
   18
 ],
id: 88057,
original_title: "A Beginner's Guide to Endings",
original_language: "en",
title: "A Beginner's Guide to Endings",
backdrop_path: "/dDYli8oDYOkgRp5f0kMqgQ1TSmt.jpg",
popularity: 1.006656,
vote_count: 4,
video: false,
vote_average: 5.75
}
],
total_results: 1,
total_pages: 1
}
```

I want to grab the id field, so I tried responds[0]['results']['id']- but it doesn't work! (responds[0]['results'] does work!)
any idea why??

Comment: `responds[0]['results']` looks like it contains an array, so you first have to extract the element to get the `id` field from.

Comment: how can I extract it?

Answer (score 4):

The `results` key references a *list* of dictionaries; you'll have to use integers to index this:

```
responds[0]['results'][0]['id']
```

gives you the `id` key of the first dictionary in that list.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Martijn `responds[0]['results']` is a list and `responds[0]['results'][0]` is a dictionary. You can see the visual representation of the json array below[image: here]. 
In order to access `id`  you'll have to use: `response['results'][0]['id']`